# Exception---SingleClientConnManager: connection still allocated

Tags: java, httpclient

I have a code to read the response of a page. it looks like this.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpEntity entity  = null;
        try{

            String it= "https://www.aaa/login";
                HttpPost httpost = new HttpPost(it);

                List <NameValuePair> ln= new ArrayList <NameValuePair>();
                ln.add(new BasicNameValuePair("un", "aaa"));
                ln.add(new BasicNameValuePair("pwd", "bbb"));
                httpost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(ln, HTTP.UTF_8));

                HttpResponse  response = httpclient.execute(httpost);
                entity  = response.getEntity();
                GZIPInputStream gis= new GZIPInputStream(entity.getContent());
            StringBuffer st = new StringBuffer();
                for (int c = gis.read(); c != -1; c = gis.read()) {
                    st.append((char)c);
                }

                    CookieStore cookieStore = httpclient.getCookieStore();
                    HttpContext httpContext = new BasicHttpContext();
                    httpContext.setAttribute(ClientContext.COOKIE_STORE, cookieStore);
                    HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet("http://aaa/index");
                    HttpResponse httpResponse = httpclient.execute(httpget, httpContext);
                    entity = httpResponse.getEntity();

                    if (entity != null) {
                        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(entity.getContent()));
                        String readLine;
                        while(((readLine = br.readLine()) != null)) {
                          System.err.println("br   :"+readLine);
                    }


                }                
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally{

            EntityUtils.consume(entity);
            httpclient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
        }
```

When I run this program i get the foll exception.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Invalid use of SingleClientConnManager: connection still allocated.
Make sure to release the connection before allocating another one.
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.SingleClientConnManager.getConnection(SingleClientConnManager.java:216)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.SingleClientConnManager$1.getConnection(SingleClientConnManager.java:190)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:401)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:820)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:754)
```

I have closed the connection in the finally block. As suggested in aonther thread I have consumed the response body before reusing the connection. what else would go wrong here?

Comment: You're calling `execute()` twice on the same `DefaultHttpClient` and it's telling you that you can't do that, apparently.

Answer (score 2):

before

```
HttpResponse httpResponse = httpclient.execute(httpget, httpContext);
```

you also need

```
EntityUtils.consume(entity);
```